# C++ GLSL shaders: "error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES" or black window

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I'm added in my simple OpenGL project very simple GLSL shaders, and it not working.

```cpp
#include <python3.6m/Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace glm;


GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path, const char * fragment_file_path){

    // Создаем шейдеры
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // Загружаем код Вершинного Шейдера из файла
    std::string VertexShaderCode;
    std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if (VertexShaderStream.is_open()) {
        std::stringstream sstr;
        sstr << VertexShaderStream.rdbuf();
        VertexShaderCode = sstr.str();
        VertexShaderStream.close();
    }

    // Загружаем код Фрагментного шейдера из файла
    std::string FragmentShaderCode;
    std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
    if (FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
        std::stringstream sstr;
        sstr << FragmentShaderStream.rdbuf();
        FragmentShaderCode = sstr.str();
        FragmentShaderStream.close();
    }

    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;

    // Компилируем Вершинный шейдер
    printf("Компиляция шейдера: %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Выполняем проверку Вершинного шейдера
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Компилируем Фрагментный шейдер
    printf("Компиляция шейдера: %s\n", fragment_file_path);
    char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

    // Проверяем Фрагментный шейдер
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
        std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    // Создаем шейдерную программу и привязываем шейдеры к ней
    fprintf(stdout, "Создаем шейдерную программу и привязываем шейдеры к ней\n");
    GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

    // Проверяем шейдерную программу
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    if (InfoLogLength > 0) {
        std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    }

    glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
    glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

    return ProgramID;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Инициализируем GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Ошибка при инициализации GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    glfwDefaultWindowHints();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);  // Включаем сглаживание
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // Мы хотим использовать OpenGL 3.3
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
//    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); // Мы не хотим старый OpenGL

    // Открыть окно и создать в нем контекст OpenGL
    GLFWwindow* window; // (В сопроводительном исходном коде эта переменная является глобальной)
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Невозможно открыть окно GLFW. Если у вас Intel GPU, то он не поддерживает версию 3.3. Попробуйте версию уроков для OpenGL 2.1.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

//     Инициализируем GLEW
    glewExperimental=true; // Флаг необходим в Core-режиме OpenGL
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Невозможно инициализировать GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }


    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);


    // Массив 3 векторов, которые являются вершинами треугольника
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    // Это будет идентификатором нашего буфера вершин
    GLuint vertexbuffer;

// Создадим 1 буфер и поместим в переменную vertexbuffer его идентификатор
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

// Сделаем только что созданный буфер текущим
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

// Передадим информацию о вершинах в OpenGL
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Включим режим отслеживания нажатия клавиш, для проверки ниже
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);


    // Создать и откомпилировать нашу шейдерную программу
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );


    do {
//        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Устанавливаем наш шейдер текущим
//        glUseProgram(programID);

        // Рисуем треугольник...

        // Указываем, что первым буфером атрибутов будут вершины
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                0,                  // Атрибут 0. Подробнее об этом будет рассказано в части, посвященной шейдерам.
                3,                  // Размер
                GL_FLOAT,           // Тип
                GL_FALSE,           // Указывает, что значения не нормализованы
                0,                  // Шаг
                (void*) nullptr     // Смещение массива в буфере
        );

// Вывести треугольник!
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Начиная с вершины 0, всего 3 вершины -> один треугольник

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Сбрасываем буферы
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Проверяем нажатие клавиши Escape или закрытие окна
    while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
}
```

I see black window (if I write

```cpp
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

else i see errors:

*Compiling shader: SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader*
***0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES***

*Compiling shader: SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader *
*Creating shader programm and linking...*
***error: linking with uncompiled/unspecialized shader***

)

Vertex shader:

```c
#version 300 es

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;

void main() {
    color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Your system seems to support [OpenGL ES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php) (rather than [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php)). Change the version specifier in the shader(s) (from `#version 330`) to `#version 300 es`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510889/how-can-i-know-which-opengl-version-is-supported-by-my-system

Comment: Rabbid76, `printf("%s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));` print **3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8**. And if I set version to `#version 300 es` then I see **0:2(1): error: No precision specified in this scope for type \`vec3'** in `color = vec3(1,0,0);`

Comment: Or **3.0 Mesa 19.0.8**, if i not write `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);` and other

Comment: And if I add `precision mediump float;` then I see red triangle! Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice here:

> ```
> GLuint programID = ...
> ```

You might actually successfully create and link your program object, but you never **activate** it! You have to add `glUseProgram(programID)` somewhere before your draw call.

Comment: Thanks, I see... I was comment it when I debugging it. I was fix it, see comment